# HighCharts: Link target in SVG

Tags: html, iframe, highcharts

I am programming a HighCharts dashboard that runs inside an iFrame (customer requirement). I need links generated by SVG inside HighCharts to break out of that frame:

http://jsfiddle.net/m3RkQ/

Commonly, I would do that using `<a href="link" target="_blank">link</a>`, but HighCharts seems to ignore that and always stay within the frame.

Any help is greatly apreciated!

Comment: Well, I opened you example and link works, so what is wrong ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan, do the links open in a new window for you? On Opera 12 and Chrome 28, they load example.com into the "result" frame of jsfiddle, ignoring the target.

Comment: Indeed, but it will not open in new window, because <a href=""> elemetn in transformed to SVG element, so as a result parameter linke target="_blank" is skipped during conversion.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Does HighChart deliberately cut the param away, or am I making a mistake? The "target" attribute seems legal: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#AElementTargetAttribute

Comment: Excatly, highcharts parse <a> element to SVG and "remove" parameters like target.

Comment: So it isn't possible... Do you want to answer the question? I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Yes sure, I added info about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML element is transformed to SVG element, so parameters like target is skipped.